# Which schema should I choose on citus deployment

Tags: postgresql, citus

I installed a multi machine cluster using citus following [this docs](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v7.5/installation/multi_machine.html) (1 coordinator, 2 nodes). After finish the installation guide I noticed that is created a citus schema besides default public schema. Also the default configuration pointing to public schema as default schema doesn't work at least I specify in the postgresql.conf file.

My question is in which schema should I work, Should i continue working in public schema or there is some particular configuration over citus schema?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use public schema with Citus. Citus schema contains some citus specific objects so don't worry about that. You can create other schemas and use them as well.